# Launching DialogFragment from Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment

There is a `RecyclerView` in which there is an `item`, I need to open the `DialogFragment` on click.

To switch to a regular `Fragment` using I write the following:

```
  holder.ll_main.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentBabyIsland fragment = new FragmentBabyIsland(); // you fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                    R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        });
```

To go to DialogFragment, I write the following

```
 holder.ll_main.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            openDialog();
        });

    private void openDialog() {
        DialogSort dialogSort = new DialogSort();
        dialogSort.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "SortDialog");
    }
```

But due to the fact that it is an Adapter, it swears at `requireActivity()`
How to fix it?

Comment: You can use `v.getContext()` to get context . ultimately `((AppCompatActivity)v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()` . Or instead of doing that you can provide a callback interface to calling component and write `openDialog` code there . Or you can have a constructor field in Adapter. using a callback Interface is a better option .

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter define `Activity` as:

```
private AppCompatActivity mActivity;
```

Then change your constructor to:

```
public MyAdapter ( AppCompatActivity activity , ArrayList<MyItem> list ) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
}
```

After you do this, you can use `mActivity` to show the dialog:

```
DialogSort dialogSort = new DialogSort();
dialogSort.show( mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "SortDialog");
```

Note that if you already use `Context`, replace it with `AppCompatActivity` or use them both in the constructor. It should be better if you just replace it.